# MVC C# DropDownListFor установка и получение значения

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Пересмотрел кучу кода по MVC, Везде примера на 500 строчек кода минимум.

Есть список справочник Plane (ключ `key.plane`)
Есть текущая запись InstanceC (ссылка на справочник `InstanceC.ID_plane`)

Как просто из контроллера загруженного списка установить значение и считать выбранное значение пользователем?

У меня есть следующий код:
**AccountController.cs**

```
public ActionResult ClickDetails(String slctplane, String Description,String SaveInstance, string AddInstance, string ActivePlane, string RestartInstance, string GeneratePassword, string ResetDB, String DelInstance)
{
            if (ActivePlane != null)
    {
      String id_plane = slctplane; // Выбранный тарифный план
    }
```

}

**Модель:**

```
public class Plane
{
    // ID - тарифного плана
    [Key]
    public int key_plane { get; set; }
    // Название тарифного плана
    public String Name_plane { get; set; }
    // Кол-во пользователей
    public int Num_users { get; set; }
    // Максимальный размер БД
    public int Size_db { get; set; }
    // Максимальная частота обращений в минуту н инстанс
    public int Freq_in_minute { get; set; }
    // Цена в месяц в $
    public int Price_usd { get; set; }
    // Цена в месяц в р.
    public int Price_r { get; set; }
}
```

**Модель**

```
public class InstanceC
{
    [Key]
    // ID - инстанции
    public int key_Instance { get; set; }

    //Пользователь, кому пренадлежит инстанция String
    public String ID_user { get; set; }

    // ключ тарифного плана


    //Ключ сервера, куда будет обращаться IOT
    public int ID_Server { get; set; }
    // Login MQTT
    public String Login_inst { get; set; }
    //Password MQTT
    public String Password_inst { get; set; }

    public int SetStatusForBroker { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }

    public int ID_plane { get; set; }
    public String Name_plane { get; set; }

    public int Price_usd { get; set; }
    public int Price_r { get; set; }
    public int Num_users { get; set; }

    public int RealStatus { get; set; }
    public String Name_server { get; set; }
    public String Name_domain { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
У меня в Details.cshtml есть следующий код

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Подробнее/";
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

</head>




<body>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ClickDetails", "Account", FormMethod.Post))

{




    <div>


        <h2>Подробнее</h2>

        <div class="cloud-box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Информация о инстанции</h3>

                </div>

            </div>



  @foreach (var i in ViewBag.Details)

  { 
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <table class="table cloud-data">
                        <tbody>


                            <tr>
                                <td>Название</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="Description" type="text" value="@i.Description" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">



                                    <button name="SaveInstance" value="@i.key_Instance" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></i>
                                        Сохранить
                                    </button>



                                    <button name="DelInstance" value="@i.key_Instance" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></i>
                                        Удалить
                                    </button>



                               </td>
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
    <td>Тарифный план</td>








    <td>







                                    <button type="button" value="" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ActivePlaneDlg">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i>
                                        Активировать
                                    </button>




                                    <div class="modal fade" id="ActivePlaneDlg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ActivePlaneTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="ActivePlaneTitle">Активация тарифного плана</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    Старый тарифный план будет аннулирован.
                                                    Активировать и оплатить новый тарифный план?
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">

                                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="ActivePlane" name="ActivePlane" value="id_plane=1">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i>
                                                        Да
                                                    </button>

                                                    <!--
                                                                                                        <input type="submit" name="ActivePlane" value="Сохранить" />
                                                                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Да</button> -->
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Нет</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>




                                </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Статус тарифного плана</td>
                                <td>
                                    <font color="green">Активирован</font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Дата продления</td>
                                <td>01.01.2019</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Автопродление</td>
                                <td>Активировано</td>
                            </tr>



                            <tr>
                                <td>Сервер</td>
                                <td>@i.Name_domain</td>
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <td>Пользователь</td>
                                <td>
                                    @i.Login_inst


                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-cloud btn-cloud-danger btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RebootInstanceDlg">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>
                                        Перезапуск
                                    </button>






                                    <div class="modal fade" id="RebootInstanceDlg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="RebootInstanceTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="RebootInstanceTitle">Перезагрузка</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    Вы уверены, что хотите перезагрузить инстанс?
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                   <!-- <button type="button" name="RestartInstance" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Да</button>

                                                    <input type="submit" name="RestartInstance" value="Да" />-->


                                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="RestartInstance" name="RestartInstance" value="id_instance=1">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>
                                                        Да
                                                    </button>     

                                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Нет</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Пароль
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @i.Password_inst
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-cloud btn-cloud-danger btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ResetPasswordInstanceDlg">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
                                        Сгенерировать
                                    </button>


                                    <div class="modal fade" id="ResetPasswordInstanceDlg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ResetPasswordInstanceTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="ResetPasswordInstanceTitle">Генерация нового пароля</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    Сгенерировать новый пароль?
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">


                                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="GeneratePassword" name="GeneratePassword" value="id_plane=2">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
                                                        Да
                                                    </button>                                                    

                                                   <!-- <button type="button" id="GeneratePassword" class="btn btn-secondary" value="id_psw=1" name="GeneratePassword" data-dismiss="modal">Да</button>  -->


                                                    <!--<input type="submit" name="GeneratePassword" value="Да" />-->

<!--
                                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="resetdb" name="ResetDB" value="id_plane=1">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                                                        Сброс БД
                                                    </button>
                                                    >-->
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Нет</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>




                                </td>
                            </tr>

<!----------------------------Начало: Список доступных портов---------------------------------------------------->


                            @foreach (var a in ViewBag.PortsDetail)

                            { 





                            <tr>

                                <td>Протокол</td>
                                <td>
                                   @a.NamePort
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <td>Порт №</td>
                                <td>
                                    @a.NumPort
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <hr>

                            }
<!---------------------------Конец: Список доступных портов------------------------------------------------------>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Сброс БД</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    Это сотрет все сохраненные сообщения в БД.
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <form action="https://*/console/9751325/details/reset" class="pull-right" id="reset-form" method="post">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="resetdb" name="ResetDB" value="id_plane=1">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                            Сброс БД
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>API</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <strong>API ключ</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <code>0942387c-de7c-4241-2349da3-e59e4c1afdf6</code>
                </div>
            </div>

      }  
        </div>
   </div> 

}

</body>
</html>
```